# Using to_jsonb(NEW) and execute

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger, jsonb

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION change_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO static_table_name (content) VALUES (to_jsonb(NEW));
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' SECURITY DEFINER;
```

↑ is working, but I'd like to have opportunity to send target table name for inserting.

So,
by the code above, I was able to use dymanic_table_name,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION change_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$
  DECLARE
    dymanic_table_name TEXT;
  BEGIN
    dymanic_table_name := TG_ARGV[0];

    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO '  || dymanic_table_name || ' (content) VALUES (' || to_json(NEW) || ');';
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' SECURITY DEFINER;
```

but it fails, when try to insert result of 'to_json' function...

ERROR:

```
ERROR:  "{"またはその近辺で構文エラー
LINE 1: ..._table (content) VALUES ({"id":43,"...
                                    ^
```

※ Sorry for Japanese syntax ( *´艸｀)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use dynamic SQL like this:

```
EXECUTE
   format(
      'INSERT INTO %I (content) VALUES (to_json($1))', 
      dymanic_table_name
   )
   USING NEW;
```